# Keras fit_generator Validation Data TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: deep-learning, keras, anaconda

I'm trying to run CUHK03 Person Re-ID script by Ning-Ding ( Implementation of Ahmed et. al.'s paper using Keras)
see https://github.com/Ning-Ding/Implementation-CVPR2015-CNN-for-ReID

Error text reads as follows:

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
in ()

    ----> 1 main("E:\DL\cuhk-03.h5")

in main(dataset_path)

    17 model = generate_model()
    18 model = compile_model(model)
    ---> 19 train(model, dataset_path)
    20
    21 def train(model,

in train(model, h5_path, weights_name, train_num, one_epoch, epoch_num, flag_random, random_pattern, flag_train, flag_val, which_val_data, nb_val_samples)
    39 rand_x = np.random.rand()
    40 flag_train = random_pattern(rand_x)
    ---> 41 model.fit_generator(Data_Generator.flow(f,flag = flag_train),one_epoch,epoch_num,validation_data=Data_Generator.flow(f,train_or_validation=which_val_data,flag=flag_val),nb_val_samples=nb_val_samples)
    42 Rank1s.append(round(cmc(model)[0],2))
    43 print (Rank1s)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)

    89 warnings.warn('Update your ' + object_name + 90 ' call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
    ---> 91 return func(*args, **kwargs)
    92 wrapper._original_function = func
    93 return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)

    2023 epoch = initial_epoch
    2024
    -> 2025 do_validation = bool(validation_data)
    2026 self._make_train_function()
    2027 if do_validation:

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I am using Jupyter Notebook in Anaconda on Windows 10(x86).
Keras version 2.1.3
Python version 3.6.3
Tensorflow backend (1.4.0)

Comment: from error message it looks like `validation_data` is a float. Check where it's coming from. Probably it's from the dataset.

Comment: The validation_data is a float value. That is the data that is used for training as well, since we have to scale the data(/255 since it is rgb value) . The code by Ning-Ding has been executed with the same, I don't understand why this like throws an error as when I tried bool(3.5) in the interactive shell, python 3 didn't throw an error.

Comment: Have you managed to resolve this?

Answer (score 11):

Ok, so that `validation_data` is a generator returned by

```
Data_Generator.flow(f,train_or_validation=which_val_data,flag=flag_val)
```

When `do_validation = bool(validation_data)` is executed, calling bool on an object will call `nonzero` or `len` if any of them is defined. In this case, `Sequence` implements `len` so it checks `if len(Sequence) == 0`. Your issue is that `len` returns a `float` (which is an error) so when it tries to convert it in a `bool`, it fails.

Assert that `len` returns an `int`.

Credit goes to Dref360 at https://www.bountysource.com/issues/54744813-fit_generator-throws-error-on-validation-data-being-float-data-type

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot.

Comment: I had the same error but in a different context.  [This article helped me discover the problem](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/54744813-fit_generator-throws-error-on-validation-data-being-float-data-type).  The `__len__()` method on my generator was returning a float.

Comment: @Goodword thanks, I've updated the answer to include the solution.

Comment: This answer saved my life.

Comment: Thank you! Re-implent __len__() in the way that it returns a int value

Answer (score 0):

I've passed by the same problem and I just want to supplement the answers already given.

As it's said above the "[..]issue is that `len` returns a float (which is an error) so when it tries to convert it in a bool, it fails". However, which `len` are you referring to?

It occurs most probably because you are using the keras generator template, which has the following definition in it.

```
def __len__(self):
return np.ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)
```

So as it has been said, make sure it is going to `return` and integer. Therefore, it fixes the problem:

```
def __len__(self):
return int(np.ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size))
```